# Radius of a circle inside the Google map visible region

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the radius of the circle that is inscribed inside the rectangle that is a visible region on screen...Google map sdk is providing only the nearLeft, farLeft, nearRight and farRight... With this I can get is the following:

[image]

But what I need is:

[image].

I have been using the following code:

```
    public static double getMapVisibleRadius(GoogleMap map) {
    VisibleRegion visibleBounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    LatLng center = visibleBounds.latLngBounds.getCenter();
    LatLng northEast = visibleBounds.nearLeft;
    // r = radius of the earth in km
    double r = 6378.8;
    // degrees to radians (divide by 57.2958)
    double ne_lat = northEast.latitude / 57.2958;
    double ne_lng = northEast.longitude / 57.2958;
    double c_lat = center.latitude / 57.2958;
    double c_lng = center.longitude / 57.2958;
    // distance = circle radius from center to Northeast corner of bounds
    double r_km = r * Math.acos(
            Math.sin(c_lat) * Math.sin(ne_lat) +
                    Math.cos(c_lat) * Math.cos(ne_lat) * Math.cos(ne_lng - c_lng)
    );
    return r_km; // radius in meters

}
```

Which is provideing radius of circle in first image.

I have also tried using the distancebetwwen from location to find the middle point of farleft and nearleft... I have been planning to find the distance between center of the map and thus found middle point. However I was not able to get the Latlng of that point.. So I was not able to proceed..

```
VisibleRegion visibleBounds = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    float[] distanceBetweentopAndBottomLeftCorners = new float[1];
    float[] distanceBetweenMiddleOfLeftAndCenterOfVisibleRegion = new float[1];
    LatLng topLeftCorner = visibleBounds.farLeft;
    LatLng bottomLeftCorner = visibleBounds.nearLeft;
    Location.distanceBetween(topLeftCorner.latitude, topLeftCorner.longitude, bottomLeftCorner.latitude, bottomLeftCorner.longitude, distanceBetweentopAndBottomLeftCorners );
    float centerOfVisibleRegionLeftToScreen = distanceBetweentopAndBottomLeftCorners [0]/2;
   // Here I am unable to proceed since the above calculated value is a float and not Latlng. My idea was to find the distance between this value and center of visible bound;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can add the code done so far for future visitors to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are measuring the distance between top left and bottom left coordinates so it gives you vertical distance(up to bottom). To measure horizontal distance you should use 'farLeft and farRight' or 'nearLeft and nearRight' coordinates(left to right).

```
VisibleRegion visibleBounds = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
float[] distanceBetweenLeftAndRightCorners = new float[1];
LatLng topLeftCorner = visibleBounds.farLeft;
LatLng topRightCorner = visibleBounds.farRight;
Location.distanceBetween(topLeftCorner.latitude, topLeftCorner.longitude, topRightCorner.latitude, topRightCorner.longitude, distanceBetweenLeftAndRightCorners );
float thisIsWhatYouNeedInMeters = distanceBetweenLeftAndRightCorners [0]/2;
```

This way you will get the distance at the top of the screen or at the bottom of the screen but I guess all horizontal distances will be the same so you get what you need.

If you want to measure exactly how you want below are the coordinates you can pass to distanceBetween(). As I mentioned results would not differ.

```
LatLng leftCenter = new LatLng((visibleBounds.farLeft.latitude + visibleBounds.nearLeft.latitude)/2, (visibleBounds.farLeft.longitude + visibleBounds.nearLeft.longitude)/2);
LatLng screenCenter = visibleBounds.latLngBounds.getCenter();
```